# client server python -C++

Tags: python, c++, client, protocol-buffers

I have written simple client(C++) server(Python) communication using boost asio and protocol buffer. I pass array  back and forth . My problem when I pass array from server ( python) to client (C++) I have only about 50 elements of my first array on the C++ output. How to solve this problem I have to pass 10 arrays with 10000 elements.

piece of code  client c++ reading data on client :

```
            boost::asio::transfer_exactly(65536) */);
    boost::asio::streambuf b;
    boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type bufs = b.prepare(10000000);
    size_t n = socket.receive(bufs);

    b.commit(n);
    std::istream is(&b);
    std::string s;
    is >> s;


     object1.ParseFromString(s);
     std::cout << object1.DebugString();
            // this line doesn't output allarray's elemenents. 


}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    //std::cerr << e.what(luuu) << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "\nClosing";
std::string dummy;
    }
```

Python server:

```
    import socket 
    from test_pb2 import Person
    import dataf_pb2

    host = 'localhost'
    port = 10000
    backlog = 55
    size = 1024 
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(backlog)

    element = dataf_pb2.ParticleMatrix()
    for i in range(1000):
    element.xPox.append(i * 0.53434)

    for i in range(1000):
    element.yPox.append( i * 0.53434)

    for i in range(1000):
    element.zPox.append(i * 0.53434)

    message= element.SerializeToString()
    element1 = dataf_pb2.ParticleMatrix()

    while 1: 
      client, address = s.accept()
      print ('Client connected')
      data = client.recv(50000)
      print data
      if data:
      object1 = dataf_pb2.ParticleMatrix()
      object1.ParseFromString(data)
      print object1.__str__()
      print object1.ListFields()
      client.send(message)
      client.close()
```

Comment: `data = client.recv(50000)` -- how did you determine the 50000 here? Is that large enough? I guess you need some message communication protocol, where the sender encodes the length of the message in a header of fixed length.

Comment: On python side it warks perfect and 50000 is ok . But on C++ client i wrote 10000000 ( I changed the size of buffer many times , but always had the same result). So I think problem  is not with buffer

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted using [sendall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall) instead of just send? I've been working on a similar client/server (in pure c++ though) and personally it looks like a buffer problem to me.

Another thing I would suggest is attempting to capture the loopback (if client/server are running from same machine) and looking at the packets to see what/how much data is actually getting sent. Wireshark is a useful tool for this.

Also would be useful to add in some error handling on send/recv so you can check total bytes that are actually being sent if you don't want to do the packet capturing.

Comment: No send looks ok.  Now I have found the problem  but dont know how to solve it. my buffer size = 5000 as I assigned ( the maximum size is 429496).  My problem in this line with  b.commit(n);
std::istream is(&b);  And the size of string s   is 119, which is not  acceptable .